# Post Form data using AngularJS and Java Spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp file in which i am uploading a file. For backend handling of file i made a controller in spring. But it return error in console: **String parameter 'name' is not present** ? My Code is -

**JSP File**

```
<input class="fileInput" type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
<button type="button" ng-click="saveProfile()">Update</button>
```

**JS File**

```
$scope.username = 01238339595;
$scope.saveProfile = function() {
                    var input = document.getElementById('fileInput');
                    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append("name", $scope.username);
                        formData.append("file", input.files[0]);
                        console.log("form data " + formData);
                        $http.post("save-avatar", formData)
                            .success(function(data, status, headers,config) {
                                                        console.log('Success');
                                                    })
                            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                                        console.log('Error');
                                                    });
                    }
                };
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "save-avatar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    if (file.isEmpty())
        throw new IOException("File Field is Empty");

    ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    String absoluteDiskPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");

    File folder = new File(absoluteDiskPath + "/avatar/");
    if (!folder.exists())
        folder.mkdirs();

    File avatarFile = new File(folder, name + ".jpg");
    if (!avatarFile.exists())
        avatarFile.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(avatarFile);
        outputStream.write(file.getBytes());
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null)
            outputStream.close();
    }

    return "redirect:/avatar-profile?name=" + name;
}
```

In my config xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10485760" />
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks to @Rossi for the controller.

On the rest, just change JS code to `$http.post("save-avatar", formData, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the above controller method, use this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save-avatar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void UploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
    MultipartFile file=null;

    while (itr.hastNext()) {
        file = request.getFile(itr.next());
        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        //Do your stuff here.......
    }
}
```

Comment: excuse me. I have followed your instruction but it return
`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]`

Comment: Do you have this in the config?? <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/

Comment: Make sure you have right dependencies and config setup.

Comment: Can you share what you have for the dependency and in the config.xml?

Comment: okay, I edited it on above. I think the problem is JS Code. Is `var formData = new FormData();` right? i think we need a multipart form data, not a normal form data